# Can mysqld process be killed?

Tags: mysql, linux, macos, pid

I tried to kill mysql process since it was giving me an error as: 
*The server quit without updating PID file*. But whenever I killed the process by PID, it created a new PID and the process persisted. Any explanation on this issue will be appreciated! The code I tried was as follows:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
sudo kill -9 [PID]
```

MySql was installed on Mac from .dmg file. And it was initially working fine, the error happens after it has already worked for a while.

Comment: Killing MySQL with `-9` can very likely result in data loss or database corruption. Most likely recoverable, but it's not a good idea in general.

Comment: Also I think you need to provide more background information if you want to get an answer. What operating system are you running, how did you install mysql (from a package, from source, etc)?

Comment: I am using Mac with mysql installed from .dmg file.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to stop it using the daemon manager with service (linux):

```
service mysql stop
```

and for Mac:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I tried to run you code, it says "-bash: service: command not found".

Comment: Hi Psidom, can you tell me the OS in wich you have the mysql server installed.

Comment: Sure, it's OS X EI Capitan 10.11.2

Comment: It is still giving me the error "MySQL server PID file could not be found!" slightly different though.

Comment: Try this, go to the activity monitor and force quit the mysql process then run this: sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart

Comment: There is no process called mysql in the activity monitor, but only mysqld, and as I stated in the question, I can not really quit it no matter in command line or in the monitor. It simply refreshes with a new PID. And I tried the restart method. It still fails with the same error as in the question.

Comment: OK check this: go here and see if you can find a file like this: /usr/local/var/mysql/{username}.pid if you find it, locate your my.cnf file, it can be in a directory like /usr/local/mysql/x.x.xx/my.cnf, where x.xx.xx is your mysql version, if it is there add this at the bottom: pid-file = /usr/local/var/mysql/{username}.pid.  Don't forget to replace {username} with yours.

Comment: I have a bunch of "my.cnf" files here. Which one should I modify?

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/federated/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/ndb/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/ndb_big/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/ndb_binlog/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/ndb_rpl/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/ndb_team/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/rpl/extension/bhs/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/rpl/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/mysql-test/suite/rpl_ndb/my.cnf

Comment: I recommend you to add it to all of them, cause I don't know which is the one you are running, I assume those are different settings for different situations to run the server, add it to all of them to be sure we hit the one it is being used.

Comment: I just did that but still no luck. I don't have the /usr/local/var directory actually. The .pid file locates in /usr/local/mysql/data which needs sudo permission.

Comment: Ok, I don't know which server you have installed in your computer, for testing purposes I install XAMPP for Mac it installs you apache+php, mysql and proftpd, it has graphical manager to admin the servers, I suggest you, if you can, to uninstall the one you have and install this one, it has never give any problem to me.

Comment: I guess it's probably time to uninstall and reinstall it since it has become too complicated. Thank you all the same for your help, and I'll vote for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, and hope you can have it up and running ASAP.